# is it possible for content Entity to have multiple links

Tags: 8, entities, routes, navigation

If I have: entity type: car_make and entity content: car_model

by default: car_model will have 5 links:

```
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/test/entity/{car_model}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/test/entity/{car_make}/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/test/entity/{car_model}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/test/entity/{car_model}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/test/entity",
 *   },
```

the problem with above is: i dont know in that particular links belong to which car_make?

is it possible for an entity to have multiple canonical (or others) links?

something like:

```
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/test/{car_make}/{car_model}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/test/{car_make}/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/test/{car_make}/{car_model}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/test/{car_make}/{car_model}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/test/{car_make}",
 *   },
```

so I could have multiple routes for car_model canonical links:

- /admin/test/Honda/1
- /admin/test/Honda/2
- /admin/test/Honda/3
- /admin/test/Toyota/1
- /admin/test/Nissan/1

if it's possible, how to build/implement it?

Comment: While it could be possible to implement a route like /admin/test/{car_make}/{car_model}/delete, it doesn't make sense, since every entity is unique, so {car_make}/{car_model} doesn't help to identify an entity. The only one that makes sense is /admin/test/{car_make}/add, which close to what the Node module does with /node/add/{node_type}, where *node_type* is a bundle.

Comment: even if every entity is unique, and if i use the default generated links (see: my first code snippet above), then the add-form make sense, i can create form to add entity (based on {car_make} type's field), but the others, like collection `/admin/test/entity` how to list data frm particular car_make? (only list Honda car for example) or in canonical path: `/admin/test/entity/1` (1 is car_model ID) how do i know if `1` is belong to which {car_make}? and each of the links, it will be great for url cosmetic for SEO if the could have a nice/re-presentable url: for example: /test/honda/1

Comment: See what the Node module does. If you want _nice_ URLs, use path aliases. Drupal just needs to know the entity type and the entity ID to find an entity.